# Blender Smoke Simulation Glitch: Why are parts of my smoke flashing?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm having an issue where rendered smoke in a domain with many collision objects starts "flashing" in certain spots. The collision objects are transparent cylinders with 6 faces, set as both smoke collision and rigid bodies (to enable better collision bounds). The smoke is emitted from a plane at the bottom of the domain. I have the test render up on an unlisted YouTube video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqC8d4MfYsM

Smoke domain settings:

[image]

Smoke emitter settings:

[image]

And the rigid body settings:

[image]

[This is a link to a screenshot of the scene in Blender.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drHWK.png)

Any thoughts why the smoke flashes a bit from about 1 second to around 7.5 seconds? Is it just matter of increasing my domain resolution (and render time), or is there something else I'm missing?

Be gentle, I'm a bit of a Blender noob! :-)

Comment: Did you try to scale the domain so it to be large enough those cylinders to fit in it ? It's not clear from the screenshot whether domain's width is enough, but it's likely that the height isn't - the half of the right-most tube is inside of domain, the half - outside

Comment: The tubes protrude from the front and back of the domain purposely, as the effect I'm going for is smoke filling in around empty hexes. A few also protrude on the sides, as they are out of frame and don't matter much. That, said, I could easily try matching all of the objects up and see where that gets me.

Comment: You could also check whether those tubes have overlapping faces (vertices / edges / other non-manifold geometry). Also you might want upload .blend file with this example on the [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if someone would like to investigate it

Comment: @MrZak I reworked the scene slightly using array modifiers (instead of just duplicating the same tube over and over), and made everything fit into the domain. Smoke now crosses in front of the tubes, which technically shouldn't happen since the tubes and the domain are the same depth. Here's a link to the blend file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/447/